# Spring-Data @oneToMany with @EmbeddedId get not mapped to a single property

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to build a oneToMany relation between a Rent table and a RentAgreement table, the rent table has a composite key rentKey

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "Rent")
public class Rent {

    @EmbeddedId
    @Column(name = "rentKey")
    private RentKey rentKey;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="rent", cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "rent", allowSetters=true)
    private Set<RentalAgreement> rentalAgreements;
...
```

The RentKey is

```
@Data
@Setter
@Getter
@Embeddable
public class RentKey implements Serializable{
    private String rentStartDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "agent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "rents", allowSetters=true)
    private Agent agent;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "rents", allowSetters=true)
    private Client client;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "propertyRent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "rents", allowSetters=true)
    private PropertyRent propertyRent;
    ...
```

and the RentAgreement  is

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "RentalAgreement")
public class RentalAgreement {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name="agent_id", referencedColumnName="agent_id"),
            @JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="client_id"),
            @JoinColumn(name="propertyRent_id", referencedColumnName="propertyRent_id")
    })
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "rentalAgreements", allowSetters=true)
    private Rent rent;
    ...
```

When I run the code, I get

org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(agent_id, client_id, propertyRent_id) of com.mikason.PropView.dataaccess.documentEntity.RentalAgreement.rent referencing com.mikason.PropView.dataaccess.commercialEntity.Rent not mapped to a single property

Could anyone tell me where I did wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: Remove the `@JoinColumns`, hibernate should have enough information from the inverse mapping and `EmbeddedId` to do the mapping.

Comment: `@EmbeddedId
    @Column(name = "rentKey")
    private RentKey rentKey;` Remove the `@Column` annotation. You are not mapping (and should not have) a column named `rentKey`

Comment: Is it working? am facing similar kind of issue...